# Expected an assignment and instead saw an expression in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner at Reactjs. I am trying to use fetch to fetch comments from jasonplaceholder api and display them.
I am getting the following error :- Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

```
Code

import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Comments extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            comments: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(comments => {
                this.setState({ comments: comments })
            });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.comments, "comments")
        return (
            <div className="conatiner">
                <p>All Comments :-</p>
                {
                    this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
                        <ul key={comment.id}>
                            <li>{comment.email}</li>
                            <li>{comment.body}</li>
                        </ul>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: typo: add a `return` inside map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work ( return element inside the map)

```
this.state.comments.map((comment) => (
                        <ul key={comment.id}>
                            <li>{comment.email}</li>
                            <li>{comment.body}</li>
                        </ul>
                    ))
```

simple syntax of map in reactjs is

```
array.map((element,index)=>(
<h2>{element.name}</h2>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return because it is a callback function.

```
this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
  return (
    <ul key={comment.id}>
      <li>{comment.email}</li>
      <li>{comment.body}</li>
    </ul>
  );
})
```

More simply.

```
this.state.comments.map((comment) => (
    <ul key={comment.id}>
      <li>{comment.email}</li>
      <li>{comment.body}</li>
    </ul>
))
```